# Theme Forest How do I add data content

Tags: themes, uploads, content

Total WordPress Novice here.  I am using a Theme forest template and wish to add content but keep getting a critical admin error. Do I  Reinstall, delete,activate or start over with the  template. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reinstalling the theme isn't a bad idea (unless you've added custom code to the theme--which is not recommended practice anyway). But there's not enough information here to fix your problem. If you have FTP or file access to your WordPress files, check your `error_log` file in your WordPress install for specific errors and share that here.